# JQuery target scrolls up or down, but not pixels

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to just target the JQuery scroll up or down element. At the moment I am targeting a specific pixel but what If I want to target either scroll up or down?

Code so far is:

```
var $sr = $('.fixed-div');

if ($(this).scrollTop() > 44) {
        $sr.css({
            'position': 'fixed',
            'top': '44px'
        });
    }

    if ($(this).scrollTop() < 88) {
         $sr.css({
            'position': 'static',
            'top': '44px'
        });
    }
```

This does not work as I scroll down the .fixed div has a element on top which is 44px but as I scroll up the element has another div (Header) on top which makes 88px. So scrolling down is fine but scroll up the element is still in the 44px position? I have used position static because when I scroll to the top I want all elements to be stacked as normal.

Any ideas?

Comment: Please provide the html as well.

Comment: please post enough code for a minimal reproducible example